# Rosparam in RqtGui

Tags: python, rosparam, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, is there a way in Ros to implement a funcition to get/set parameter of rosparam server similar to rosservice in python?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188960/rosparam-in-rqtgui/) by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-08-05**:
Are you asking how to get/set parameters programmatically using python? Or are you asking how to get/set parameters using the rqt gui?

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2014-08-05**:
Programmatically using python because I need to create a rqt plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This [link](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Parameter%20Server) should have all the information you need.

There are many ways to get:

```
global_name = rospy.get_param("/global_name")
relative_name = rospy.get_param("relative_name")
private_param = rospy.get_param('~private_name')    
default_param = rospy.get_param('default_param', 'default_value')

# fetch a group (dictionary) of parameters
gains = rospy.get_param('gains')
p, i, d = gains['P'], gains['I'], gains['D']
```

And set:

```
rospy.set_param('a_string', 'baz')
rospy.set_param('~private_int', 2)
rospy.set_param('list_of_floats', [1., 2., 3., 4.])
rospy.set_param('bool_True', True)
rospy.set_param('gains', {'p': 1, 'i': 2, 'd': 3})

rospy.get_param('gains/P') #should return 1
```

You can do a lot of other things like delete params, check and see if a param exists, list all params, etc. All of it is covered in that link.

[This](http://wiki.ros.org/rosgui_paramedit) might be of interest to.  It looks like someone already had something like this but used the rx stuff (I just skimmed it, you might want to look closer).

Lastly, if you do build a plugin, please let people know about it  [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt/Plugins) to prevent duplicate efforts. I also notice on that page that the description of the  [Node_Manager](http://wiki.ros.org/node_manager_fkie) plugin says something about managing params, you might want to look at that to.

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2014-08-06**:
Perfect, thanks for you time

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-08-06**:
Glad to help. If that answers your question, please mark it as the answer (the little check mark).

**Comment by [Edmodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/14091/edmodi/) on 2014-08-06**:
Done. Thanks

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-08-06**:
Is http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_reconfigure not an option?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2014-08-07**:
It looks like that only works for parameters that are setup with dynamic_reconfigure.

"In the future, arbitrary parameters that are not associated with any nodes (which are not handled by dynamic_reconfigure) might become handled. However, currently as the name indicates, this pkg solely is dependent on dynamic_reconfigure that allows access to only those params latched to nodes."

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-08-08**:
Yeah, I just thought if OP specifically wants to handle non-dyn-reconf parameters wasn't clear.